# Does scala/typesafe Config offer some way how to configure pluggable implementation of the trait?

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

I am facing following task of providing implementation of the trait as a configuration option.
I have following class hierarchy :

```
trait Storage {
  def store()
}

object LocalStorage extends Storage {
   def store(){ ... }
}

object RemoteStorage extends Storage {
   def store(){ ... }
}
```

Having a configuration in property file:

```
storage.class = "com.xxx.LocalStorage"
```

Having an implementation on the persistence layer:

```
class CheckPersister{
val storageType = ConfigFactory.load().getString("storage.class")
val storage: Storage = Class.forName(storageType).asInstanceOf[Storage]
...
}
```

Is there a better way of dealing with this kind of configuration? I am using Typesafe configuration.

Thx

Comment: Not that I know of.  You could pimp the `Config` yourself to provide something like `getClassType[T](propName:String):Class[T]` or `getInstance[T](propName:String):T` if you find this to be common to your system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly specifying the name of the class in the config file looks like a bad idea. Would something like this be acceptable instead?

```
storage.location = "local"

class CheckPersister {
  val storageType = ConfigFactory.load().getString("storage.class")
  val storage: Storage = storageType match {
    case "local" => LocalStorage
    case "remote" => RemoteStorage
    case x => throw new RuntimeException(s"Invalid storage type $x specified")
  }
  ...
}
```

In this way you can't accidentally instantiate a class you didn't intend.

Comment: It's rare that you would ever need a completely unbounded list of types for what to instantiate.  More realistically, you have a few to chose from and this speaks well to that.  If you ever added a new type I'd have to imagine it's inside of a release cycle anyway, so you just add support for that to this match statement and off you go.

Comment: I was considering this as well but just wanted to if there are some better alternatives which I am not aware of. E.g. for Akka I found system.dynamicAccess.getClassFor[Actor](loggerName)